# If Statement is not functional

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am stuck with this code, I don't know whats wrong with my if statement but it keeps displaying T1T on every sheet. Please help. Thank you.

```
Public Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

  Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)

  If Sheet.Name = "USA" & i And Range("D20").Value = "Branch Codes" Then

    Sheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "B1"

  Else

    Sheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "T1T"

  End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: **MAYBE** change `Range("D20").Value` to `Sheet.Range("D20").Value`?

Answer (score 1):

You will also want to set it to `sheet.range("D20")` if you want it to read from the given sheet. Otherwise, it will refer to D20 on the first sheet.

```
If Sheet.Name = "USA" & i And Sheet.Range("D20").Value = "Branch Codes" Then
```